# How to apply specific shipping charges if order is below X amount?

Tags: shipping, magento-1.9.2

I am working on magento-1.9.2 version. I want to apply the specific amount of shipping charge if order is below x amount ?
i tried with flat rate and table rate but it doesn't help me out

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: version is 1.9.2xx

Answer (score 1):

- Goto admin>Promotion>Shopping cart rules
- Create Shopping Cart rules
- On this condition tab put logic shopping

  **Subtotal > = 50**

[image]

[image]

- Enable Flat rate from System -> Configurations -> Shipping Methods
  and put your shipping Charges.It is work when subtotal less 50